# Need help detecting collision between two objects

Tags: java, collision-detection

I'm having some issue regarding collision detection in a game i am making. I have the distance between the two objects using this:

```
    double b1Dist = Math.sqrt((obOneX - obTwoX) * (obOneX - obTwoX)
            + ((obOneY - obTwoY) * (obOneY - obTwoY)));
    double b1DistTwo = b1Dist - objectOneRadius;
    b1DistFinal = b1DistTwo - objectTwoRadius;
```

and I was attempting to do collision detection with this:

```
  if (b1DistFinal <= objectOneRadius && b1DistFinal <= objectTwoRadius ) {
            return false;
        }
         else
            return true;

    }
```

I'm new to java so i'm sure theres probably much better/more efficient ways to write the above, however could anyone please help me out or point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the efficiency of that. However, if `obOneX`, `obOneY`, etc are the x and y coordinates of the centers of the objects, then your formula is wrong.

The variable `b1DistFinal` is the distance between the outer edges of the two objects. If it's zero, those objects have collided.

Try:

```
if (Math.abs(b1DistFinal) < 0.001) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Note: Rather than checking if it is exactly zero, I am checking if it is *close* to zero to allow for some rounding error during the double arithmetic.